# Cordova 3.4 (Android WebView) does not show up authentication dialog

Tags: android, cordova, webview, basic-authentication

I am working on an android cordova-3.4 mobile app that accesses a remote server using jsonp.

Resources on the server are protected with basic authentication. In normal browser a login dialog appears but not in cordova app.

Is it a bug or feature? And whht is the best way to work around this limitation?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

Ingvord.

Comment: Hi, I implemented a kind of backdoor for cordova client on my server using servlet filters -- seems to be a suitable solution for our needs.